# Authorization failure with Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get Google Maps working on my Android project.
I did everything by the book but nothing works...

- Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.
- Cannot resolve Identity from identityId. Dispatching as
  Identities.PSEUDONYMOUS.
- Ensure that the "Google Maps Android
  API v2" is enabled.       Ensure that the following Android Key
  exists:
  API Key:  Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>):
  GoogleCertificatesRslt: Package signed with unknown certificate*

The API key, fingerprint and package name are correct.
Restricting and unrestricting the API key makes no difference.
Switchen between debug and release fingerprint makes no difference either.
It simply doesn't work whatever I am trying.
Any suggestions what I am missing, doing wrong or lousy documented?

Comment: did you make release key?

Comment: Yes, the app has already been released. The map is a new feature. As I said, neither the debug or release fingerprint with package name is working. As well leaving the key unrestricted doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you defining your API key? Is it in the manifest file?

Comment: I have this line in local.properties: MAPS_API_KEY="AbCdEfGhi1234...", this line in mainifest: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was located in local.properties:
Instead of MAPS_API_KEY="AbCdEfGhi1234..." it should read MAPS_API_KEY=AbCdEfGhi1234...

Don't surround the key with ""...

Comment: HOLY! You just saved my day. I spend hours to figure out why my maps stop working after moving key to other properties files...Thanks so much.